# Flutter apk installed but but cannot be found/opened

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I have been spending some weeks to try out to figure out this problem but I cannot manage to get it to work.

Context:

**Flutter run**

- I can perform "flutter run" and it will launch the app on my phone.
- After closing the app, I cannot see it in the apps page. I cannot search for it.
- The only way way to "reach" the app is to go to settings -> apps. Here I cannot open the app, the only option is to uninstall it.

**Flutter build**

- I can build an app. "flutter build apk" works fine.
- If a previous app version of the app is installed, It fails to install the apk.
- If I uninstall the previous app from settings -> apps, I can install the new apk. But I cannot open it. It only says "Done" and "Open" is grayed out.

**What I have tried:**

- Uninstall app from settings -> app
- flutter clean
- Removed signing from build.gradle
- Change singing release to debug
- flutter build apk -split-per-api
- This guide https://flutteragency.com/how-to-fix-release-apk-is-not-working-properly/
- Uninstalling "for all users"
- Running "adb shell am start com.example/.mainActivity" -> Works
- "adb shell pm list packages" shows my packet id

**Additional information**
I don't know if it matters, but I recently added signing config and released an appbundle to the App Store. Might there be issues with conflicting appbundle and apk file?

My "flutter doctor -v"

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale sv-SE)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at /Users/*/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (4 weeks ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/*/Library/Android/sdk/
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/*/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.38.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 100.0.4896.122

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

´´´

Comment: I've recently released an app myself. If I do `flutter run` it installs and is visible on the apps screen and can even be launched without flutter connected. I also have no problem overriding the app that has been installed from the playstore. The first things that I can think of are a too old android version on your phone or a conflicting app id e.g. com.example.myapp. Make sure that you have assigned a unique app id.

Comment: How do I know if my app id is conflicting? Since I have uploaded the app to App Store with this ID is seems to me that the id should be unique and mine.

The android version is 11. Which isn't super old.

Answer (score 18):

**I solved it**

Problem was my intents.

How they were:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />          
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />        
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

How they should be:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />            
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />        
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: No f*ing way! I can't believe this worked! I tried every other solution - This is the one I needed. Thanks @K B

Comment: K B, Where did you find this solution ?

Comment: Thank you soo much for posting your answer here. Saved my life.

Comment: missions passed +respect.
thank you

Comment: this also solves deep linking issue