# Cant open Flutter app after build to release

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, release

So I just spend the whole night messing up and reinstalling android studio and vscode and flutter cause I was trying to build an apk for my app that's ready enough to pass out to some friends for testing. when my phone is connected to my computer I can debug my app no problem so I thought no big deal lets push out an apk and show off my work. What a nightmare this has been and still is.

I followed this step by step guide to building an android app... https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android
So once I finally got all the mystery errors out enough for it to build an apk I copied the file over to my phone and installed it. Well soon as it installed and still on the pop up I see 2 buttons, Close and Open, only open is greyed out. I cant open my app up.

I tried changing the targetSdkVersion down to my phones android version.I tried building out every possible version and appbundle and apk for all the processors and I just cant seem to get a variant to open. I have the key.properties file all linked up, I used the keytool like in the guide.

Has anyone else build out flutter app but cant open it? I'm stumped... The first few attempts I was getting extra popups for googles play protect so I went and turned off that feature. Ive had my phone in developer mode for years now so I know unknown sources are allowed.

It installs fine, but doesnt create an icon anywhere to be used. Once i exit out of the original install popup the only way Id know it was on my device is to go into settings/apps and find it there, and in there the  only options are uninstall and force stop which is also greyed out. So the app is unuseable

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark but the way I fixed it was from the answer from this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978135/flutter-apk-installed-but-but-cannot-be-found-opened

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I only have the 2 entries in the intent-filter section so no need to split anything up.